# How to get user followers

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to get a list of my followers via Ruby and the Twitter API, however when I use the code you see below, my response in the terminal is:

```
#<Twitter::Cursor:0x007f8e71d922e8>
```

How can I turn that into of list with any parameters like usernames and or IDs?

My code:

```
require 'Twitter'


client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "..."
  config.consumer_secret = "..."
  config.access_token = "..."
  config.access_token_secret = "..."
end

puts client.followers
```

Answer (score 0):

as in the duplicate answer link, you can simply use collect

```
screen_names = client.followers.collect {|f| client.user(f).screen_name }
```

Comment: it gets a rate limit exceeded..too many requests error @dax

Comment: So i just added ".take(10)" at the end, but what do I do with the hash? I'm not sure how to implement it into other values? @dax
#<Twitter::User:0x007fd8daeabab8>